# Check if is an attribute is a valid DOM attribute

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I've noticed that if you take an element with jQuery you can change every attribute with the attr method. That's what supposed to do right?

Well, it's right but what if you do:

```
$('p').attr('foo','bar');
```

If you inspect the element with Chrome Tools or Firebug you will see that, in fact, it has now an attribute called foo with the value of bar.

Does anyone knows a way to do a previous check and avoid this? Can something go wrong if this happen?

Comment: "Do a previous check and avoid this". Can you explain this bit?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? The function is doing what it's designed to do by the sound of it.

Comment: Yes, imagine you're retrieving both values from the user, so the user can put whatever he wants. If he/she makes a mistake it should be ignored or give an error

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you're asking.  The "user" is the developer and the method is build to manage any attribute on a DOM element.  As with most jQuery plugins/methods, they are expected to be used according to spec, if the developer submits invalid parameters it doesn't care it just won't work.

Comment: I just want to know if there is a way to know if the attr is following the spec or it doesn't.

Comment: What spec should that be? This would mean that your JS will have to be aware of every valid attribute on every kind of element in every available doctype. It would probably be neat, but as it currrently stands, it's not possible unless you create your own list of valid attributes for each element type!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/),

> "As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set."

So you could call it first like this:

`$('p').attr('foo');`

and see if it returns an undefined value.

Comment: But this will fail if an img lacks an alt attribute. The alt is valid, foo it's not

Comment: That's true. I'm not sure how to do what you want then, short of adding all the valid attributes you care about in the spec ahead of time, so they are all there.